# Generate an array containing unique Random ints, check for duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, nodes

This is an assignment for school that I am really close to completing, but I don't have it exactly. I am supposed to generate an array of integer Nodes with 100 random numbers without duplicates by checking for duplicates.
I'm not allowed to use a Set.
I'm not allowed to just shuffle an array of numbers 1-1000.

Here is the code I have in my client class so far but it still creates duplicates:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    int j = (int)(Math.random()*1999);

 //put a random number in the first index.
    if (i == 0) {
        Node newNode = new Node(j);
        nodeArray[i] = newNode;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        if (nodeArray[k].getInt() == j) {
            j = (int)(Math.random()*1999);
            break;
        } else {
            Node newNode = new Node(j);
            nodeArray[i] = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find a duplicate it is not enough to just select a new number. You have to check the new number also as that could be a duplicate. Basically, when at index i, keep generating random numbers until you find one that is not used on position 0..i-1. When found, assign to index i and repeat for i+1.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö So change my inner most if statement to a while? Would that help fix it?

Comment: @MagdaleneB. check my answer please. it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way i would do this would be to use a List to store all the random numbers in. Then when you generate a number you can check if it already exists in the list, and get another number (this is done via recursion, or a while loop). You keep going with this until your list is full. Then go through the list creating the Nodes for your array.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(SIZE);
for (int i = 0;i<SIZE; i++) {
    addUniqueRandomNumber(numbers, SIZE*2);
}

for (int i =0;i<numbers.size; i++) {
  Node newNode = new Node(numbers.get(i));        
  nodeArray[i] = newNode;
}
```

The addUniqueRandomNumber method:

```
public static void addUniqueRandomNumber(List<Integer> numbers, int range) {
    int j = (int)(Math.random()*range);
    if (numbers.contains(j)) {
        addUniqueRandomNumber(numbers, range);
    } else {
        numbers.add(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you are assigning a new random if the first random is a duplicate in your second if statement it never checks if that random could be also a duplicate. You need to redo the loop and check if that number is a duplicate as well.

```
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    if (nodeArray[k].getInt() == j) {
        j = (int)(Math.random()*1999); //You must check if this random is also a dup
        break;
    } else {
        Node newNode = new Node(j);
        nodeArray[i] = newNode;
    }
```

Here's what I would do:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < SIZE) {
int j = (int)(Math.random()*1999);

 //put a random number in the first index.
if (i == 0) {
    Node newNode = new Node(j);
    nodeArray[i] = newNode;
    i++;
}

for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    if (nodeArray[k].getInt() == j) {
        //Do nothing
    } else {
        Node newNode = new Node(j);
        nodeArray[i] = newNode;
        i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically only increment `i` if the number is not duplicate, otherwise go through and try to find another random that is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a **helper boolean array** to keep track of which numbers were already added to the array. Review this code, it is short and concise:

```
boolean[] used = new boolean[2000];
int[] randomUniqueIntegers = new int[SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 1999);

    if (!used[num]) {
        used[num] = true;
        randomUniqueIntegers[i] = num;
    } else {
        while (used[num]) {
            num = (int) (Math.random() * 1999);
            if (!used[num]) {
                used[num] = true;
                randomUniqueIntegers[i] = num;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see the implementation above doesn't use Set or shuffling. However, you can use the test code below to see it works correctly.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : randomUniqueIntegers)
    set.add(i);
System.out.println(set.size());
```

You will see that the size of the set is equal to `SIZE` constant in each run which indicates we have all unique elements in our array.

Comment: What does while (used[num]) iterate?

Comment: @jrowe08 it doesnt iterate over sth, it just tries to find a non-used integer, when it is found while loop breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution algorithm which check after each generated number exist is or no:

```
int[] nodeArray = new int[100];
int currentIndex = 0;

while(currentIndex < 100) {
    int currentValue = (int) (Math.random() * 199);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < currentIndex) {
        if(currentValue == nodeArray[i]) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(i == currentIndex) {
        nodeArray[currentIndex++] = currentValue;
    }
}
```

Then you can sort ant print random numbers

```
Arrays.sort(nodeArray); // Sort to be easy find duplicates
for (Integer i : nodeArray) {
    System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
```